# How to set the list of ciphers and protocols to be used for sockets created by using HttpsURLConnection?

Tags: java, ssl, httpsurlconnection

The normal way to get an `SSLSocketFactory` would be to initialize a new `SSLContext` with a `TrustManager`, `KeyManager` and `SecureRandom` and use the `getSocketFactory()` method. However, this does not allow me to enable the required cipher suites or protocols.

The only configuration that `HttpsURLConnection` permits that would allow such a change is by setting its default `SSLSocketFactory`. I can create a class that extends `SSLSocketFactory` and override the `getDefaultCipherSuites()` method and wrap the sockets created by `createSocket()` to have the required ciphers and protocols set. However, this method does not allow me to initialize a `TrustManager` for the connection?

Is there a method I can do both - set cipher suites and protocols and initialize a trust manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the `SSLSocketFactory` obtained by `SSLContext.getSocketFactory()` and wrap it in a custom subclass of `SSLSocketFactory`, which delegates to the one obtained from `SSLContext`, but in `createSocket()` also sets the required cipher.

Answer (score 1):

See the JSSE Reference Guide. You can set the cipher suites via system properties.

Comment: It becomes global if set via system properties. I might want to set it just for a particular connection or even just one particular application.

Comment: Agreed. However you didn't state that requirement in your question.

Comment: Just for completeness (having just closed [this as a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24888420/372643)), the relevant system property is `https.cipherSuites`.