# How to configure SSL Cipher Suites for https in Java

Tags: java, ssl, https

I am using a third-party package for managing OAuth connections.  I would like to configure the cipher suites used by the SSL connection under the hood.  Unfortunately, the third party creates the connection with `URL.openConnection()` and I have no obvious way to reach the SSLSocketFactory in order to set the cipher suites.  Is there a way to set this through, for example, a JVM parameter?

Thanks

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17555006/372643), but the other question *can* reach the `SSLSocketFactory`.

Answer (score 6):

`URL.openConnection()` (with an `https://` URL) should use an `HttpsURLConnection`. You should be able to use the `https.cipherSuites` system property for this. (See [table in the customization section of the JSSE ref. guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization)).