# Update Ciphers list in JAVA windows

Tags: java, ssl, https

I need to send a secured request using java(jre1.8.0_65) on my Windows, 
I used the below code to configure my certs and key factory.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

//FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("certs/tester1024.pfx");
InputStream ins = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("certs/tester1024.pfx");
ks.load(ins, "1234".toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SUNX509");
kmf.init(ks, "1234".toCharArray());
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

URL obj = new URL(httpURL);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
if (connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
    ((HttpsURLConnection)connection)
    .setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
}           

connection.setRequestMethod(method);

responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

the above code works but  the list of Ciphers sent Client in the "CLIENT HELLO" does not include the Cipher TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_**256**_CBC_SHA256.

it includes this TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_**128**_CBC_SHA256

In the Client Hello Ciper list, I want this Cipherto be included.

Please let me do I need to update any thing related to JAVA on windows, because on linux same java application includes both the Ciphers.

Comment: If you use the Oracle-formerly-Sun JRE (or JDK), to use SSL/TLS suites with 256-bit symmetric cipher, or to use >128 bit symmetric cipher any other way, you must install the **JCE Unlimited Strength** download listed near the bottom of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html . If you use the openjdk JRE, as is often but not always the case on Linux, (IME) it doesn't need this step.

Comment: Thanks for the information, its working now ..  One more thing is, How to set the Client to choose a specific cipher insted of sending a big list in the CLIENT HELLO. ?

Comment: Since you are using `HttpsUrlConnection` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555006/how-to-set-the-list-of-ciphers-and-protocols-to-be-used-for-sockets-created-by-u . For plain`SSLSocket` answer would be simpler. Meta: I'm not sure why I got notified on this comment because you didn't use @, but I did. Magic, I guess.